# Using ACE framework with bind interface

Tags: sockets, interface, virtual, ace

I have Linux server with one physical interface `eth0` and 3 virtuals `eth1, eth2, eth3`. Server has 4 IP addresses, it is necessary to use a lot IP ports (more than 100k). Server has `bond0` interface with 4 addresses, for example `.1`, `.2`, `.3` and `.4`.
My application based on ACE v5.5. To open an local `1023` port I use `ACE_SOCK_Dgram` class with ctor argument `ACE_Addr = ACE_INET_Addr("0.0.0.0:1023")`. It works. How to open `1023` on another local IP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Using `ACE_INET_Addr("x.x.x.1:1023")`, `ACE_INET_Addr("x.x.x.2:1023")`, `ACE_INET_Addr("x.x.x.2:1024")`, etc in `ACE_SOCK_Dgram` ctor param provide your application to use different IP addresses and different ports. You can manage port and address as you like.